# Limiting the number of combinations /permutations in python

Tags: python, list, permutation, python-itertools

I was going to generate some combination using the itertools, when i realized that as the number of elements increase the time taken will increase exponentially. Can i limit or indicate the maximum number of permutations to be produced so that itertools would stop after that limit is reached.

What i mean to say is:

Currently i have

```
#big_list is a list of lists
permutation_list = list(itertools.product(*big_list))
```

Currently this permutation list has over 6 Million permutations. I am pretty sure if i add another list, this number would hit the billion mark.

What i really need is a significant amount of permutations (lets say 5000). Is there a way to limit the size of the permutation_list that is produced?

Comment: Do you really need the list? An iterator takes very little memory and it is as fast as (or more than) a list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), like this

```
itertools.islice(itertools.product(*big_list), 5000)
```

It doesn't create the entire list in memory, but it returns an iterator which consumes the actual iterable lazily. You can convert that to a list like this

```
list(itertools.islice(itertools.product(*big_list), 5000))
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, because it also lets you set start and stop easily.

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.islice` has many benefits such as ability to set `start` and `step`.  Solutions below aren't that flexible and you should use them only if `start` is 0 and `step` is 1. On the other hand, they don't require any imports.

---

You could create a tiny wrapper around `itertools.product`

```
it = itertools.product(*big_list)
pg = (next(it) for _ in range(5000)) # generator expression
```

`(next(it) for _ in range(5000))` returns a generator not capable of producing more than 5000 values. Convert it to `list` by using the `list` constructor

```
pl = list(pg)
```

or by wrapping the generator expression with square brackets (instead of round ones)

```
pl = [next(it) for _ in range(5000)] # list comprehension
```

Another solution, which is just as efficient as the first one, is

```
pg = (p for p, _ in zip(itertools.product(*big_list), range(5000))
```

Works in Python 3+, where [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) returns an iterator that stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted. Conversion to `list` is done as in the first solution.

Comment: @frostnational. Nice solution, works very well. Unfortunately i can only mark one answer as accepted. But this works just as well. Thank you

Comment: Or you can skip the `permutation_generator` totally and use list comprehension. Or even simpler, `[x for _, x in zip(xrange(5000), iterator)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this method to get particular number of permutations number of results a permutation produce is n! where n stands for the number of elements in a list for example if you want to get only 2 results then you can try the following:

Use any temporary variable and limit it

```
    from itertools import permutations
    m=['a','b','c','d']
    per=permutations(m)
    temp=1
    for i in list(per):
        if temp<=2:    #2 is the limit set
           print (i)
           temp=temp+1
        else:
           break
```