# Finite permutations of a list python

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I have a list and would like to generate a finite number of permutation with no repeated elements.

```
itertools.permutations(x)
```

gives all possible orderings but I only need a specific number of permutation. (my initial list contains ~200 elements => 200! will take an unreasonable amount of time and I don't need all of them)

what I have done so far

```
def createList(My_List):
    New_List = random.sample(My_List, len(My_List))
    return New_List

def createManyList(Nb_of_Lists):
    list_of_list = []
    for i in range(0, Nb_of_Lists):
        list_of_list.append(createList())
    return list_of_list
```

It's working but my List_of_list will not have unique permutations or at least I have no guaranty about it.

Is there any way around to do so? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting the number of combinations /permutations in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23722473/limiting-the-number-of-combinations-permutations-in-python)

Comment: Are you looking for a random sample of all permutations? If so -- you can pick a random set of numbers in [0 to 200!-1] and unrank them, using an algorithm like https://stackoverflow.com/a/8958309/4996248

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `islice`, which allows you to take a number of elements from an iterable:

```
from itertools import permutations, islice

n_elements = 1000

list(islice(permutations(x), 0, 1000))
```

This will return a `list` of (the first) 1000 permutations.

The reason this works is that `permutations` returns an *iterator*, which is an object that generates values to return as they are needed, not immediately. Therefore, the process goes something like this:

1. The calling function (in this case, `list`) asks for the next value from `islice`
2. `islice` checks if 1000 values have been returned; if not, it asks for the next value from `permutations`
3. `permutations` returns the next value, in order

Because of this, the full list of permutations never needs to be generated; we take only as many as we want.

Comment: This is the best solution. You might want to add a brief explanation why generators are efficient in python and that all permutations are not actually created and then filtered down to 1000.

Comment: Yeah this is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
i = 0
while i < Nb_of_Lists:
    if createlist() not in list_of_lists:
        list_of_list.append(createList())
    else:
        i -= 1
```

This will check if that permutation was already used.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to roll your own permutation. You just to halt the generator once you get enough:

```
# python 2.7
import random
import itertools
def createList(My_List):
    New_List = random.sample(My_List, len(My_List))
    return New_List

x = createList(xrange(20))
def getFirst200():
    for i, result in enumerate(itertools.permutations(x)):
        if i == 200:
            raise StopIteration
        yield result

print list(getFirst200()) # print first 200 of the result
```

This is faster and more memory efficient than 'generate of full set then take first 200' approach

Comment: The `islice()` approach suggested by @gmds is much more cleaner.

Comment: Note that in Python 3.6, `raise StopIteration` in a `generator` will raise a `DeprecationWarning`; in Python 3.7, it will raise a `RuntimeError`.